# I can't use mouse wheel scroll in Eclipse XFCE

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, mouse-gestures

I have installed Arch Linux + XFCE and installed Eclipse Mars on it.

It works fine except for the mouse scroll. Does anyone know what I should look for on this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have the same problem using Arch Linux + GNOME Shell 3.16. I also use the PyDev plugin in Eclipse Mars.

I fixed the issue by enabling the option "Show vertical scrollbar?" in Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor-> Overview Rule Minimap.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be better as a comment to SWE-JSAM's answer - and would be if I could comment.

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 15.10 w/ XFCE 4.12. Had previously had an older version of eclipse (helios? I think...) which was working fine - I'm pretty sure I was on ubuntu w/ xfce when I was using it.

SWE-JSAM's answer also fixed the problem for me.

Just figured I'd add the extra details in case someone was trying to work out what was common to these cases - it would appear to be only the Mars version of Eclipse (and pydev, assuming Folatt has that installed - although if he didn't that would mean pydev wasn't causing the problem, but rather providing a way to fix a problem that might be unfixable otherwise?)